# How to use std::string as command with the system() call?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a string into the system() shell command function. I am trying to pass a concatenated string into it like so:

```
string parameters = "Doug";
system("ps -ef|grep " + parameters);
```

It keeps giving me error because system() takes a char*. How would I go about having the system() function work. I tried putting parameters.c_str() but doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Use c_str() with concatenated string (command+parameters) before passing the string to shell

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `c_str()` on the result of the concatenation:

```
system(("ps -ef|grep " + parameters).c_str());
```

(Note the parentheses.)

Comment: Why does this work? c_str() returns `const char *`, not `char *`.

Comment: @Basilevs: `c_str()` returns a `const char*` and `system()` takes a `const char*`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: That's well interesting ([and provable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ce5ab7087ed1b48)). I didn't notice yet, there exists an operator overload for `std::string operator+(const char*, std::string)`.

Answer (score 2):

> because system() takes a char*.

Yes `system()` needs a `char*` parameter (`const char*` respectively). You can do it the following way, by constructing the complete command line to pass first

```
string cmd = "ps -ef|grep ";
cmd += parameters;

system(cmd.c_str());
```

---

Well, as it's [proven](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ce5ab7087ed1b48) from [@NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106635/how-to-run-string-in-system-command/26106662#26106662) there's a overloaded `+` operator for `std::string`, that supports the following signature

```
std::string operator+(const char*, const std::string&);
```

Thus

```
system(("ps -ef|grep " + parameters).c_str());
```

can be resolved by the compiler for having a temporary `std::string` instance as result of the `+` operation, and pass that temporary result instance's `c_str()` value as the `const char*` parameter required by the `system()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this very much (at all), I'd consider writing an overload of `system` that accepts a `std::string` as its parameter:

```
void system(std::string const &s) { 
    std::system(s.c_str());
}
```

Then the rest of the code can create `std::string`s and pass them to `system` without any problems, so your original code:

```
string parameters = "Doug";
system("ps -ef|grep " + parameters);
```

...compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
string parameters;
parameters += "ps -ef|grep ";
parameters += "Doug";
const char * command = parameters.c_str();
system(command);
```

Must be `using namespace std;` be used outside the main function

Comment: Please add context and supporting information to your answer.

Comment: int system (const char* command);  
https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/  
const char* c_str() const;  
https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/